# Implementing SNMP SendTrap using Indy components

Tags: snmp, indy, c++builder-2010

I need to report errors from my application on C++Builder via SNMP.

I started implementing SNMP SendTrap using Indy components.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::btSendTrapClick(TObject *Sender)
{
UnicodeString myEnterprise   = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5";
UnicodeString eventType      = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5.1";
UnicodeString eventDistance  = "1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5.2";

TIdSNMP * idSnmp = 0;
TSNMPInfo * infoSnmp = 0;

idSnmp                 = new TIdSNMP(NULL);
infoSnmp               = new TSNMPInfo(idSnmp);

idSnmp->Host           = edHost->Text;
idSnmp->Community      = "public";

infoSnmp->Host           = edHost->Text;
infoSnmp->Community      = "public";
infoSnmp->Enterprise = myEnterprise;
infoSnmp->GenTrap = 6;                       // I've met such values
infoSnmp->SpecTrap = 1;                      // somewhere in inet
infoSnmp->MIBAdd(eventType,"ftCritical");
infoSnmp->MIBAdd(eventDistance,"2.357");

idSnmp->SendTrap();

delete idSnmp;
}
```

But when I run application there is no udp activity in my system. When I run something like this

```
idSnmp->QuickSend(sysDescr, "public", edHost->Text, val);
```

wireshark shows 192.168.100.21 192.168.100.19 SNMP 82 get-request 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0

but when `idSnmp->SendTrap()` wireshark sees nothing (filter for wireshark is UDP portrange 161-162 in both cases)

I'll be glad to see some remarks about my code or maybe working example of SendTrap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not populating `TIdSNMP::Trap` with any values.  That is why `TIdSNMP::SendTrap()` is not sending anything.  There is nothing for it to send.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMainForm::btSendTrapClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    String myEnterprise   = _D("1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5");
    String eventType      = myEnterprise + _D(".1");
    String eventDistance  = myEnterprise + _D(".2");

    TIdSNMP *idSnmp = new TIdSNMP(NULL);

    idSnmp->Trap->Host       = edHost->Text;
    idSnmp->Trap->Community  = _D("public");
    idSnmp->Trap->Enterprise = myEnterprise;
    idSnmp->Trap->GenTrap    = 6;                       // I've met such values
    idSnmp->Trap->SpecTrap   = 1;                      // somewhere in inet
    idSnmp->Trap->MIBAdd(eventType, _D("ftCritical"));
    idSnmp->Trap->MIBAdd(eventDistance, _D("2.357"));

    idSnmp->SendTrap();

    delete idSnmp;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `TIdSNMP::QuickSendTrap()` instead:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMainForm::btSendTrapClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    String myEnterprise   = _D("1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5");
    String eventType      = myEnterprise + _D(".1");
    String eventDistance  = myEnterprise + _D(".2");

    TStringList *names = new TStringList;
    names->Add(eventType);
    names->Add(eventDistance);

    TStringList *values = new TStringList;
    values->AddObject(_D("ftCritical"), (TObject*)ASN1_OCTSTR);
    values->AddObject(_D("2.357"), (TObject*)ASN1_OCTSTR);

    TIdSNMP *idSnmp = new TIdSNMP(NULL);
    idSnmp->QuickSendTrap(edHost->Text, myEnterprise, _D("public"), 162, 6, 1, names, values);
    delete idSnmp;

    delete names;
    delete values;
}
```

Or, if you are compiling for mobile:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMainForm::btSendTrapClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    String myEnterprise   = _D("1.5.5.5.5.5.5.5");
    String eventType      = myEnterprise + _D(".1");
    String eventDistance  = myEnterprise + _D(".2");

    TIdMIBValueList *mibs = new TIdMIBValueList;
    mibs->Add(TIdMIBValue(eventType, _D("ftCritical"), ASN1_OCTSTR));
    mibs->Add(TIdMIBValue(eventDistance, _D("2.357"), ASN1_OCTSTR));

    TIdSNMP *idSnmp = new TIdSNMP(NULL);
    idSnmp->QuickSendTrap(edHost->Text, myEnterprise, _D("public"), 162, 6, 1, mibs);
    delete idSnmp;

    delete mibs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know why but I thought that when I populate snmpInfo it's enough. Obviously I missed `assigning idSnmp->Trap = snmpInfo`    But, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I copied your code literally but there is no network activity yet.

Comment: If it works, then please accept my answer so I get credit for it.  As for `idSnmp->Trap = snmpInfo`, it will leak the original `Trap` object.  Use use the `TIdSNMPInfo` that `TIdSNMP` creates, like I showed. Don't create your own at all.